# Not able to click on element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click on 'Advance Search link' , but it gives me out error says that no such element present , where mt locator point valid based on xpath I had used .

```
   <a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAdvanceSearch" class="lnkAdvancedSearchDown" onclick="javascript:ShowHideAdvanceSearch('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpLeadAgent','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpLeaseAgent','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpSaleAgent','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpContactAgent','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpFurnished','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpFloorType','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpView','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpLayout','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpTenancy','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAdvanceSearch','#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_drpReserveLeadAgent');">Advanced Search</a>
```

I tried every possible locator , .

By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAdvanceSearch']")

Comment: There may be two links available for the xpath you mentioned.

Comment: The html you provided doesn't contains ID `ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnAdvanceSearch` nor text "Advance Search link". Please provide the relevant html.

Comment: @Kishan Patel , yes there is , I also address first link using proper xpath , still it doesnt work.

Comment: You got your answer. Great.. :-) Also you can differentiate xpath using [1], [2] etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the below code. It should work.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Advanced Search']")).click();
```

If the above code returns 2 elements, then we have to use different `xpath` to differentiate those two elements.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out , here is xpath which need to be used .

//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlListingTool']/div[1]/div/div[2]/a